# Filter child entityset on parent object

Tags: c#, linq

Ok this seems insanely simple but for some reason I'm not having any luck.  I have an object lets call it Order and it has children OrderLines.  I have my foreign key relationships defined in the database so when I load up the Order object the Orderlines children is loaded.  What I want to do is filter the children later on.  So after I have loaded the Order object based on some logic I want to filter the children.  For example I realize after I have loaded the order object I want to show you only the lines that are back ordered.

```
var order = (from o in db.Orders where o.Id=9999 select o).firstordefault(); 
//bunch of code and conditions validated, complex business logic
// I need to filter the OrderLines to back order lines only
```

would like to do something like this

```
order.OrderLines = order.OrderLines.Where(ol=>ol.BackOrder==true); //this won't work
```

What's the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DataLoadOptions.AssociateWith Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.associatewith.aspx)

```
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.AssociateWith<Customer>(c => c.Orders.Where(ol=>ol.BackOrder==true));
```

Comment: this looks good but, I need to retreive the order make some decisions on whats on the order then filter the results.  So either I load the order twice, first time with everything, second time with filtered details, or find another method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify your collection from the database.  Try just creating a new variable for your backorders.

```
var backorders = order.OrderLines.Where(ol => ol.BackOrder);
```

If you want to get the orders from the database and only pull the backorders, you can do something like this:

```
var ordersWithBackOrders =
    (from ol in db.OrderLines
     where ol.BackOrder && ol.Order.Id == 9999
     group ol by ol.Order
     into orderGroups
     select orderGroups).FirstOrDefault();
```

This returns an `IGrouping<Order, OrderLine>`.  The group will only have the OrderLines where BackOrder == true, and the Key property of the group will be the Order.

The "method chain" version might be a little prettier (and leaves out the "select"):

```
var ordersWithBackOrders = db.OrderLines
    .Where(ol => ol.BackOrder && ol.Order.Id == 9999)
    .GroupBy(ol => ol.Order)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```